# How deploy spring web services on websphere 8.5

Tags: spring, maven, web, service, websphere

I'm generating with maven an EAR with a WAR module, the installation it's without problem on Server Websphere 8.5, but the application doesn't deploy it in uri (localhost:9080/ContextRoot ) 
The server websphere show the next message:

> Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: {0}

Which file searching websphere?

The structure of EAR is:

```
--EAR 
  ---Meta-inf
  ---War.war
     ---Web-inf
        ---classes
        ---lib
        ---web.xml

     ---meta-inf
        ---manifest.mf
```

Comment: This may be helpful https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/deploying-your-applications-websphere-application-server-70-part-1

Comment: How is your service defined? Is your `web.xml` a version 3.0 ? and `application.xml` version 6, if you have it?

Answer (score 0):

if webshere show that application as up and running you can go to admin console and click on the application

check if you see any service provider under Web Services Properties, if you do not see than there is some issue withe packaging/startup.

and also if it is a ear please confirm the context root you have specified in you POM while packing.

Comment: The app it's running in websphere, but i can't deploy it.
What's mean service provider under Web Services Properties ?
The context Root is the same in the WebSphere.
thx.-

Answer (score 0):

If your application is deployed successfully, you can verify context root via console in:
`Enterprise Applications > applicationName > Context Root For Web Modules`

then you can check, if you may access wsdl via:

`http://host:port/context/serviceName?wsdl`

Comment: this is a message:
Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException